# Using jQuery to navigate between divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I currently have a div which when clicked posts data to another page and reloads the div.  I would like to add a back button (`#backref`) to the new div to take me back to the previous div.  I have found several posts on this whereby you add `display:none;` to the div you want to browse to, but obviously this is my initial div so I cannot use that css.  Any suggestions on how to get round this would be appreciated!

Code I am using to achieve this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.clickthrough2').click(function () {
    // get car id
    carId = $(this).attr('id'); // get the car id to access each class element under the car div container

    $.post('referrer-ajax2.php', {
        clickthrough: $('#car-'+carId+' .clickthrough').val(),
        ref_date_from2: $('#car-'+carId+' .ref_date_from2').val(),
        ref_date_to2: $('#car-'+carId+' .ref_date_to2').val()
    },
    function (data) {
        $('#car1').html(data);
    });
});     
});
```

index.php:

```
<div id="car1" class="declined3 statdivhalf2">
<h4>Select Car</h4>

<div class="statgrid">
    <?php
    $result=$ mysqli->query($sql); 
    if($result->num_rows === 0) { echo 'No Cars in selected time period.'; } 
    else { while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 
    ?>
<div id="car-<?php echo $row['car_id'];?>">
<input type="hidden" class="ref_date_from2" value="<?php echo $date_from; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" class="ref_date_to2" value="<?php echo $date_to; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" class="clickthrough" value="<?php echo $row['car_name'] ?>" />
<a><div id="<?php echo $row['car_id'];?>" class="clickthrough2 col-5-6"><?php echo $row['car_name'] ?></div></a>
</div>

    <div class="col-1-6">
        <?php echo $row[ 'quantity']; ?>
    </div>
    <?php } } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

referrer-ajax2.php:

```
<div id="car1" class="declined4 statdivhalf2">
    <h4>Car Details</h4>

<div class="statgrid">
    <?php
    $result=$ mysqli->query($sql); 
    if($result->num_rows === 0) { echo 'No Cars in selected time period.'; } 
    else { while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) { 
    ?>
    <div id="clickthrough2" class="col-5-6"><?php echo $row['car_details'] ?></div>
    <div class="col-1-6"><?php echo $row[ 'quantity']; ?></div>
    <?php } } ?>
    <a><div id="backref">< Back</div></a>
</div>
</div>
```

EDIT:  I have tried the below be it did not work:

```
$('#backref').click(function () {
  $('.declined4').hide();
  $('.declined3').show();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of reloading the div with the new content you could create a new div each time hiding the old one. You would then cycle through them by indexing each div with either an id or (probably better) a "data-" attribute.

Comment: Do you have an example please? I have not heard of that method before.

Comment: Do you mean here create a new div with jQuery :S.  Or do you mean more the hide and unhide

Comment: In your code you are doing     
    function (data) {
        $('#car1').html(data);
    });

Change that line to hide the div and put in a new div with the new html.